# How to extract the content of a Thymeleaf Fragment?

Tags: thymeleaf

I want to extract the content of a Thymeleaf fragment to manipulate it and set it then into its target tag. The fragment itself is the title tag (I haven't even set a fragment name since the title tag alone is sufficient):

```html
<title>LDAP Registration</title>
```

The destination page (in this case the destination fragment) receives this title fragment and here I wanna manipulate the content before setting it in its place:

```html
<head th:fragment="head(title)">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Name of the Website | [["${title.CONTENT}]]</title>

</head>
```

The upper code is just a *would nice if working* example to demonstrate my intention. Also worth mentioning: I don't want to set the source title into a block fragment to being able to use `th:insert`, Iwant to keep the title complete and just gain access to the fragments content.

Is this possible to achieve?